# How does one count a number of iterations with Go?

Tags: go

So I have this small piece of code that iterates as long as needed until the difference between the value sought after is abysmal. I want to count and print the number of iterations after the code is done running and preferably in my main function (along with printing everything else I need).

Edit: Okay, I've managed to do it like this. I wonder if there's an easier way of counting the iterations and passing them to the output function.

```
func sqrt(x float64) (float64, int) {
    k := 1
    z := 1.0
    q := (z*z - x)/(2*z)
    for {
      if  math.Abs(-q) > 0.001 {
      z -= q
      q = (z*z - x)/(2*z)
      k += 1
      } else {
        break
      }
    }
    return z, k
}

func main() {
    k := 1
    z := 1.0
    z, k = sqrt(9)
    fmt.Println("Your sqrt = ", z)
    fmt.Println("Math Sqrt = ",math.Sqrt(9))
    fmt.Println("Iterations: ", k)
}
```

Comment: You can pass multiple return values with go. Simply change your function signature to look like func sqrt(x float64) (float64, int) {}

Comment: @william.taylor.09 and in the end I return z, k instead of just z if k is the name of my integer? How do I separate them for printing? I've updated my post with my original output.

Comment: See answer posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return your float value and an int (as the number of iterations). I made very minor revision to your example to demonstrate.

```
func sqrt(x float64) (float64, int) {

    z := 1.0
    i := 1
    q := (z*z - x) / (2 * z)
    for {
        if math.Abs(-q) > 0.01 {
            i++
            z -= q
            q = (z*z - x) / (2 * z)
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    return z, i
}

func main() {
    f, i := sqrt(9)
    fmt.Printf("result: %f iterations: %d\n", f, i)
    fmt.Println(math.Sqrt(9))
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you basically covered both my original question and the one I had right after the other guy helped me with the function output (passing and separating the values for the final output).

I see I've made a mistake by putting the iterations counting integer inside the if loop. I wonder if there's something else I might've done better with this exercise.

Comment: some things I would have done differently: move `return z, i` to the `else` branch and then you don't need the `break`, declare `var i int` as opposed to `i := 1` and stick `1++` at the top of the for loop. That wouldn't affect the output, just style.

Comment: don't you think that putting the iteration counter integer inside the if loop would be better because then you would know just how many iterations of reducing the value you had, instead of just for-loop iterations? Also, starting with 0 as opposed to 1.

Comment: Can make that `for` loop even more compact by moving the conditional,  setup, and incrementation into it : https://play.golang.org/p/ja6iq60qRP.  And if you really want to be cheeky, the loop itself can be completely empty: https://play.golang.org/p/ZXGM4JWdtH

Comment: @Kaedys that's legit, however I tend to opt for clarity over brevity

Answer (score 1):

You can provide multiple return values through your function:

```
func main() {
    numLoops, newNum := sqrt(9)
}

func sqrt(x float64) (int, float64) {
    <implementation>
}
```

GoPlay here: https://play.golang.org/p/R2lV41EbEd